# Why might CreatePointFont() return NULL for me?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wtl

In my WTL app Im trying to change the font of a static label. But CreatePointFont returns NULL. Why might this be?

```
CFont font;

font.CreatePointFont(120, _T("Segoe UI")); 
text.Attach(GetDlgItem(IDC_MAINTEXT));
text.SetFont(font);
```

Comment: Got a link to the MSDN page for the variant of CreatePointFont you're using?  The only ones I'm finding say it takes three parameters, the third being a DC.  Are you passing an appropriate DC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that `CreatePointFont` is returning NULL?

For a font to be set, it must remain in memory, whereas from your code snippet it appears that the variable `font` is destroyed directly after setting it.

Declare the variable somewhere that will not be deleted during the lifetime of the `text` object, such as the class if you are using an MFC object.

Comment: That was the culprit. As soon as my OnInitDialog was finished the `font` variable was destroyed.

Comment: "For a font to be set, it must remain in memory" cheers Andrew, you've just made my day! :)

Answer (score 1):

The nPointSize argument to `CreatePointFont()` is in tenths of a point, perhaps your size of 12/10 = 1.2 points is too small. You probably meant to pass in `120`.

On a lighter note, you may also want to visit the [ban comic sans](http://bancomicsans.com/main/) web site, if you're using this for a business application.

Comment: Your right the size is wrong but it still does return NULL. And as for the Comic Sans I just took whatever font I had. I agree that comic sans shouldn't be used.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that AtlGetControlFont() also return NULL?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is not too verbose on the fail conditions, but my guess it you don't have the named font on the machine

Check if it is listed by the `EnumFontFamilies` function (quote form the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chxkwcsd.aspx)):

> The Windows EnumFontFamilies function can be used to enumerate all currently available fonts

Comment: I've tried with all the fonts installed, from Comic Sans to Arial.